# SQL Create view statement using WITH keyword

Tags: sql, view, psql, create-view

I am having issues writing this Create view statement in SQL. I want to get personID, first name, and last name from a table for people that go to the University of Colorado (uid = 2). Then I want to use the WITH clause to combine this table with my body_composition table and print out everything in the body_composition table as well. Here is the exact definition of the query I am making.

> First, write a query that returns the person’s id (pid), first name
>   (fname) and last name (lname)    from all people who are from the
>   people who go to the University of Colorado. Then, place that query in
>   a WITH clause and use it as a common table expression (CTE) to combine
>   the result with the body composition table via an inner join to get
>   the body compositions for people who attend the    University of
>   Colorado.

I try and run my create view statement I get this error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "what" LINE 7: WITH
>   what.body_composition as c

Here is my code for this create view statement along with the tables that I am using.

```
CREATE VIEW withclause AS
SELECT a.pid, a.fname, a.lname
FROM what.person AS a
INNER JOIN what.university AS b
on a.uid = b.uid
WHERE uid = 2
WITH what.body_composition AS c
SELECT *
FROM what.body_composition;
```

Here are the three tables that I am using

```
                  Table "what.university"
 Column          |         Type          |                        Modifiers                        
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 uid             | integer               | not null default nextval('university_uid_seq'::regclass)
 university_name | character varying(50) | 
 city            | character varying(50) | 


 Table "what.body_composition"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 pid    | integer | not null
 height | integer | not null
 weight | integer | not null
 age    | integer | not null


    Table "what.person"
 Column |         Type          |                      Modifiers                      
--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 pid    | integer               | not null default nextval('person_pid_seq'::reg class)
 uid    | integer               | 
 fname  | character varying(25) | not null
 lname  | character varying(25) | not null
```

Comment: What database are you really using?  MySQL does not support `with`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using psql

Comment: Homework assignment? This person posted something nearly identical: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26207028/398670

Answer (score 3):

Based on the problem description I'm pretty sure this is what you want:

```
CREATE VIEW withclause AS

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT p.pid, p.fname, p.lname
  FROM what.person as p
  INNER JOIN what.university as u
  ON p.uid = u.uid
  WHERE p.uid = 2
)

SELECT cte.pid, cte.fname, cte.lname, c.age, c.height, c.weight
FROM cte
INNER JOIN what.body_composition c on c.pid = cte.pid;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fdc59/1) (based on Postgres which I'm assuming you're using based on the psql tag).