# WITH keyword in sql CREATE VIEW statements

Tags: sql, view, psql, create-table, create-view

I am having a difficult time with this create view statement that uses the keyword `WITH` to group tables together. I am using plsql so I can use the `WITH` keyword where as if I was in Mysql I could not. The query that I am trying to write is

> First, write a query that returns the person id (pid) of all people
>   who are taller than 70 inches  that do not attend the ‘University of
>   Colorado’ (Hint: uid != 2). Then, place that query in    a WITH clause
>   and use it as a common table expression (CTE) to update all people in
>   that set so that  their university is now the ‘University of
>   Colorado’.

Right now when I run my query in sql I get this error.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 3:  SELECT a.pid

Here is the code that I have written for this query then I will post the tables that I used. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
CREATE VIEW withclause2 AS

WITH cte(
    SELECT a.pid
    FROM what.person as a
    INNER JOIN what.university as b
    ON a.uid = b.uid
    WHERE a.uid != 2
)
SELECT cte.pid
FROM cte
INNER JOIN what.body_composition as c
ON c.pid=cte.pid
WHERE c.height > 70;
```

The tables are

```
                Table "what.university"
     Column      |         Type          |                        Modifiers             
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 uid             | integer               | not null default 
 university_name | character varying(50) | 
 city            | character varying(50) | 


           Table "what.person"
 Column |         Type          |                      Modifiers                
--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 pid    | integer               | not null default nextval('person_pid_seq'::regclass)
 uid    | integer               | 
 fname  | character varying(25) | not null
 lname  | character varying(25) | not null

 Table "what.body_composition"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 pid    | integer | not null
 height | integer | not null
 weight | integer | not null
 age    | integer | not null
```

Comment: you are missing AS key word it should be WITH CTE ( ) AS

Comment: Okay it tells me i create a view when I change that but is it the right view?

Comment: As per the assignment, you need to put the two conditions ( height and uid ) and get all the rows and then using CTE , you need to update condition. so view needs more changes.

Comment: This assignment doesn't require you to write a view at all, but a cte and use that cte as source for an update.

Comment: Btw, you might want to post the assignment that corresponds to the solution you've attempted. You talk about creating a view, but the assignment text talks about using a cte for an update query. Not the same thing.

Comment: Homework assignment? This person posted something nearly identical: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26207028/398670 . Good on you for providing the code, error, and schema though, +1.

Comment: @CraigRinger yes it was lol. I did well on it though Thanks to everyone for the help!!!